# How it the experience with new Amazon's Cluster GPU Instance of EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

Amazon released EC2 - Cluster GPU Instances and I wonder what's your experience with it? Is it stable, does it require a lot of time to install new drivers, SDK etc. before you deployed your CUDA code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't yet deployed a gpu instance, but I can tell you that the OS image already has the drivers setup for you.

Now in terms of installing CUDA, and getting your code ran thats anotother stody. If you haven't tried EC2 at all then I can tell you on a normal instance - I can install gcc/g++ and svn; setup a repository and have my code run in 5-10 minutes.

EDIT: I was looking through the documentation and found this: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Cluster_GPUs_Install_Driver.html#d0e18924 this talks about reinstalling or updating the NVIDIA drivers

Comment: To me, the drivers wasn't up-to-date, I needed to install it manually.
Here is a gist to help you https://gist.github.com/Kmaschta/8de62ea5f73346a8f0c61b75fe36c93b